# How can i use the linq join function result inserted in a viewbag from razor view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core, razor-pages

How can I use the linq join function result inserted in a viewbag from razor view?
In following code I am try set list of Photo in `ViewBag.photos` to using it in `ViewPage` Razor page.

```
var result = photos.Join(projects, (pho => pho.ProjectID), (pro => pro.ProjectID), ((pho, pro) => new { photos = pho })).ToList();
ViewBag.photos = result;
```

When I try used the `ViewBag.photos` in view page, give me some error.

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-6 col-md-6" data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="60">
                @foreach (var item in (IEnumerable<Wenar.Models.DomainModel.Photo>) ViewBag.photos)
                {
                    <img src="~/ProjectPhotos/@item.Photo1;" />
                 }
</div>
```

That error mention is:

> $exception    {"Unable to cast object of type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[<>f__AnonymousType6`1[Wenar.Models.DomainModel.Photo]]'
> to type
> 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Wenar.Models.DomainModel.Photo]'."} System.InvalidCastException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create list of objects type of `Wenar.Models.DomainModel.Photo`, you can use `Select` method:

```
... ((pho, pro) => new { photos = pho }))
    .Select(s => new Wenar.Models.DomainModel.Photo{ photoId = s.photoId, photoName = s.photoName })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: this error be solve, but the all property (Fields) be null.

Comment: You need to assign them when creating an object type of `Photo`.

Comment: The Photo have tow property(photoID,photoName), how can i assigning. Please describe more with an example.Thanks

Comment: Added example. But I really will suggest you read some basic and intermediate `c#` stuff, before going further.

Comment: Thank you, its was very useful. I added one mistake ; after src pic, for them it was not worked.

Answer (score 1):

The objects you are creating with your query are with [anonymous type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types) - `new { photos = pho }`.

If you want to use collection of type `Photo` you need to change the query to something like

```
var result = photos
                .Join(projects, (pho => pho.ProjectID), (pro => pro.ProjectID), ((pho, pro) 
                     => new Photo() { photos = pho }))
                .ToList();
```

You don't need to cast the collection to `IEnumerable` in order to use `foreach` on it, and you don't need to call `ToList()` on your query if you need only to `foreach` the collection.